# What kind of relationship do I need

Tags: entity-framework, model-view-controller

I am stuck on figuring this out. MVC 5, EntityFramework
My project revolves around a Job. Every Job has multiple ChangeOrders. I have that setup fine. A Job has one Customer. That works fine as well. my problem is with the Customer Employees. The Customer class has a one-to-many relationship with the CustomerEmployee class. Every Customer Employee has a basic properties plus a Role property. Super,PM,Accountant, or Admin. Well when I create a job, I need to select a CustomerEmployee Admin/PM etc...
What relationship would this be? A many-to-many relationship? In my mind, the Job class would need to have a CustomerEmployeeSuperId, CustomerEmployeePMId, CustomerEmployeeAdminId and CustomerEmployeeAccountantId.

Because right now all it has is CustomerEmployeeId

How do I do this?
Current Setup

```
 public class Job
{
    //job
    public int JobId { get; set; }
    public int? JobNumber { get; set; }
    public string JobName { get; set; }
    public string JobDescription { get; set; }


    public int? GeoAreaId { get; set; }
    public virtual JobMisc.GeoArea GeoArea { get; set; }

    public int? JobClassId { get; set; }
    public virtual JobMisc.JobClass JobClass { get; set; }

    public int? JobTypeId { get; set; }
    public virtual JobMisc.JobType JobType { get; set; }

    public Int64? CustomerId { get; set; }
    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ChangeOrder> ChangeOrders { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PurchaseOrder> PurchaseOrders { get; set; }

    public int? CustomerEmployeeId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CustomerEmployee> CustomerEmployees { get; set; }
}

public class Customer
{
   [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
   public Int64 CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public Int64? CustomerPhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public Int64? CustomerFaxNumber { get; set; }
    public string CustomerAddress { get; set; }
    public string CustomerCity { get; set; }
    public string CustomerState { get; set; }
    public int? CustomerZipcode { get; set; }
    public string CustomerWebsite { get; set; }
    public string CustomerOtherShit { get; set; }
    public bool? CustomerIsHidden { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<CustomerEmployee> CustomerEmployees { get; set; }
    public List<Job> Jobs { get; set; }
}

 public class CustomerEmployee
 {
    [Key]
    public int CustomerEmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string CustomerEmployeeFirstName { get; set; }
    public string CustomerEmployeeLastName { get; set; }
    public string CustomerEmployeeEmail { get; set; }
    public Int64? CustomerEmployeePhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public Int64? CustomerEmployeeCellNumber { get; set; }
    public Int64? CustomerEmployeeFaxNumber { get; set; }
    public bool? CustomerEmployeeIsHidden { get; set; }
    public string CustomerEmployeeRole { get; set; }

    public Int64? CustomerId { get; set; }
    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }

    public int? JobId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Job> Jobs { get; set; }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, for the individual job, it would be a one to many relationship.  For multiple jobs, it could be many to many.

Is it possible that an employee who is an Admin might also be pressed into service as a tester for certain jobs?

I'd recommend created a child table for JobRoles, one that links to the JobID, a CustomerEmployeeID, and a JobRoleID (assuming the possibility of the JobRoles being flexible).

Hope this helps...

Comment: I am not in front of computer. When I get home I will post my code. Thanks for the response.

Comment: you got me in the correct direction. I used this as a guide  thanks  http://www.ojdevelops.com/2014/01/multiple-many-to-many-associations.html